# Why are there so many interpretations with the Bible?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, nature-of-god, christian-living, tradition

I would like to ask, WHY must there be so many interpretations of scripture? there are so many interpretations of certain verses, denominations and such, and this can be confusing for people (especially those who are baby Christians).

Now, about what Paul said about convictions, even though Paul says that believers has personal convictions and to be convinced in his own mind, however it’s like many times when a believer has a conviction on something, it’s like they will shove their convictions down other believers throats and act as if that THEY have the truth and the other person is not a true believer or going to hell or something.

Even though this is not God’s fault, but why must he allow all of this division in the Believing community like this?

Edit: In fact, when it comes to any beliefs in the believing community (not just convictions), they would act like that they have the truth and that others are wrong or not true believers or going to hell!

Comment: You might as well ask the same of the works of Shakespeare or the theory of Cold Fusion. Any body of knowledge attracts genuine experts, self-opinionated idiots and people out to make money by any means possible. The result is a spectrum of truth, devious falsehood and downright, crackpot nonsense which the discerning step carefully through, avoiding the bad and choosing the good. But in this instance one might be guided by the Holy Spirit of God in one's careful path.

Comment: Pro 25:2  It is the glory of God to conceal things, but the glory of kings is to search things out.

Comment: I think the question needs more focus. Better to pick a particular issue and examine the variation of belief, then examine why that variation exists. But this question is far, far too  broad and all-encompassing.

Comment: The question in itself is good, however it may prove too broad.

Comment: If nobody noticed that I deleted all the answers to this question in an attempt to be fair to the one question that got flagged.  You can't use the Bible (alone) to answer this question, otherwise it becomes a Truth question.